# How to make Sharepoint subsite readonly without break inheritance

Tags: powershell

I use this script to switch permission into subsite, but when I have special permission for specific directory, all right is broken.
Can you help me please?

```
Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=0)]
  [string]$LogFilePath,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)]
  [string]$SiteUrl,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=2)]
  [string[]]$exclusionSitesTitles
)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
$webs = $site.AllWebs | ?{-not ($exclusionSitesTitles -contains $_.Title)}

function checkPermissions([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignmentCollection]$roles)
{
    $roles | Out-File -Append -FilePath $logfilepath
    $roles | %{
        if($_.RoleDefinitionBindings.Count -eq 1 -and $_.RoleDefinitionBindings.Contains($guestPermission))
        {
            $_.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll();
        }
        else
        {
            $_.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll();
            $_.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($readPermission);
        }
        $_.Update();
    }
}

function checkLists($web)
{
    $web.Lists | %{
        if($_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
        {
            checkPermissions($_.RoleAssignments)
        }
    }
}

$webs | %{
    $readPermission = $_.RoleDefinitions.GetByType([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleType]::Reader);
    $guestPermission = $_.RoleDefinitions.GetByType([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleType]::Guest);
    $_.Url | Out-File -Append -FilePath $logfilepath
    if($_.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
    {
        checkPermissions($_.RoleAssignments)
    }
    checkLists($_)
    $_.Dispose();
}
$site.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not possible: a sub-site (a list, a folder, an item) has:

- Either the same permissions than its parent. In this case, permissions cannot be edited at all at the child-level.
- Or unique permissions. In that case, you can do whatever you want (including *copying* parent permisssions + add new ones), but anything done at the parent-level will never impact the child.

Comment: I want to keep all unique permission but switch it to read.

Comment: "switch to" = edit permissions. No way.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169432/switch-permission-on-file-and-folder

Comment: Yup, and...? The question you're referring to: 1. Has no answer. 2. Actually states you have to break role inheritance to achieve specific permissions on an item... Trust me: there's no way in SP to have both inherited and unique permissions on an item. Even conceptually this is wrong...

Comment: It's not my question. I know there is no way to have inherited and unique permission. => I just want to change all permission on item who have unique permission to read.

Comment: (item AND folder)

Comment: Permissions on webs, lists, folders, items = the same thing. Please, explain with full sentences what's your point.

Comment: Ok sorry, so, I have my item : $item, I want to do a foreach in $item.roleassignment to change all permission to "read"

Comment: To help you to understand with my bad english, I have this : http://puu.sh/n0rb6/533bf20e01.png

Comment: I found my solution, posted here : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169432/switch-permission-on-file-and-folder/169454#169454

Comment: Your link is nothing else than breaking role inheritance and set custom permissions on the item. How does that answer your question "How to make Sharepoint subsite readonly without break inheritance"?

Comment: Too difficult to explain in english, sorry ^^ But yes, my link answer my question, I don't break inheritance in all site, I just check where inheritance is broken to change permission to read. ;)