# Switch permission on file and folder

Tags: powershell

I made a script that load recursively all item and fold with unique permission, and I want to switch all permission on these items and folder to read. How can I do that?

```
Function GetFiles($folder)
{ 
   Write-Host "+"$folder.Name
   foreach($file in $folder.Files)
   {
       Write-Host "`t" $file.Name
   }

   # Use recursion to loop through all subfolders.
   foreach ($subFolder in $folder.SubFolders)
   {
       Write-Host "`t" -NoNewline
       GetFiles($Subfolder)
   }
 }
```

Comment: Before doing this, I suggest this article about the impact of unique permission scopes in a list : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg128955.aspx

Comment: I know but it's for a client... I didn't have th choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if($folder.item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq "True"){
    foreach($role in $folder.item.RoleAssignments){
        if($role.RoleDefinitionBindings.Name -ne "Read")
        {
            $role.RoleDefinitionBindings.RemoveAll()
            $role.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleRead)
            $role.Update()
        }
    }

   }
```